# Форматирование времени

Tags: ruby-on-rails

У меня есть дата `<%= article.data %>` в таком формате `2018-05-16`. я это заменил на : `article.data.strftime("%d.%m,%A")`, вопрос такой, можно ли как-то день недели указать по-русски?

Comment: Конечно: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats Если вы про Rails. Да и без Rails можно применить гем `i18n`.

Comment: Благодарю. Так и сделал.